# Why do python linters not detect method names that do not exist?

Tags: python, linter

I am using VS code and linters do not detect if I try to call a method on an object that doesn't exists.
This means I am not aware of the issue until I run the code. Linters seems to check if a regular function exists but for some reason it doesn't check for object methods.

This seems like simple error checking but it doesn't exist for some reason. How do I make linters flag this error?

Comment: Use type annotations and a static type checker.

https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Without type annotations, the linter doesn't know what sort of object you're dealing with. Maybe this variable actually contains an instance of some other class that *does* implement the method? The linter can't know for sure. `mypy` is the right answer

Comment: This is the problem with "duck typing".  Since the linter can't know what object will actually be in a reference when you try to make it `<ref>.quack()`, it can't tell if that reference will always contain a duck.  - IDEs try to do this so they can help you with syntax, but they often get it wrong because it's a really hard problem.  In sharp contrast, it's a very easy thing for a Java linter/IDE/etc. to do because of the strong typing.  All of this is why types were added to Python.  They don't change the actual operation of the code.  They exist just for this sort of stuff.

Comment: `mypy` and `type annotations` was the answer. Thanks all!